# PHP Parse webpage with GET Request using file_get_contents on paginated page

Tags: php, http, get, pagination, file-get-contents

I am trying to parse a webpage using file_get_contents. For method post, I am able to parse which is the first page in the list. After this, the page contents are listed via pagination.

How can we parse contents of paginated pages with the GET request?

For example : http://sample.com/results?page=3

Code:

```
$data = array(
        'page' => 1
        );

    $opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
      'method'=> 'GET',
      'headers' => $http_response_header,
       'content' => http_build_query($data),
       'timeout' => 100
        )

    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $listfile1 = file_get_contents("http://sample.com/results?",false, $context);
```

I get 0 records for the paginated page.

Comment: I would recommend using cURL instead for more complex URL parsing examples, like yours.

Comment: @divix thanks.

I had tried with cURL as well and the results were same. The file_get_contents is executed inside a loop. Is it required close any stream or session after each loop?

This is because If I try with URL [link](http://sample.com/results?page=2), first in the loop, returns the parsed second page which is correct and then afterwards empty.

Comment: Make sure are passing all required headers (if there are any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the same function listed above, There was a custom function defined which was breaking the pagination.

Yet I have changed the url also.

```
       $listfile1 = file_get_contents("sample.com/results?page=".$number,false, $context);
```